# immediate window

Tags: eclipse, immediate-window

Is there anyplace in the eclipse ide that I can enter immediate code while stoped at a breakpoint?

thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's called the **Display** window in Eclipse.  Menu Item: Window/Show View/Display

To run command you need to type then select the text in the display window and select one of the two J icons in the window.

Comment: Is there an option to execute the input without opening the context menu?

Comment: Does anyone know the keyboard shortcut to this J "execute" button?

Comment: I'd hit a breakpoint, but the buttons were grayed out - seems you have to highlight the text (mentioned above but I missed it) to run it. (Via http://stackoverflow.com/a/2506767/845584)

Comment: In Eclipse 2022-06, this window is called the **Debug Shell**.

Answer (score 21):

Note: as mentioned in [Debugging with the Eclipse Platform](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/), you can use the Display View to **scrapbook your live code**.

Meaning, while you have a live debug session:

[image: live debug session]

, you can run/debug some expressions or code in a Display view:

[image: display view]

[Example](http://nuancesofdhaval.wordpress.com/):

[image: Example]

---

See [My favorite Eclipse view](http://larsho.blogspot.com/2008/07/my-favorite-eclipse-view.html)

- To execute the code and display the returned value, push the button with a "`J`":
- If you just want to execute some code that doesn't return a value, push the button with an arrow "`>`" and a "`J`":

The standard output will be printed to the Console view.