# Interactive Debugging Grails

Tags: grails

How do you start a debug console at a specific point in Grails? I am using GGTS, and whenever I enter a breakpoint, I get the Debug Screen, which is fine, but I only get to examine variables. I need to be able to have a console in which I can call methods with the variables' values at that point, where the breakpoint is. I install this plugin,

http://grails.org/plugin/console

but it only gives me a grails console in the browser, I dont understand what it is it's purpose.

Any help please?

P.S: To help understand what I mean, I want something similar like Ruby on Rails has, an interactive debugger.

Comment: The purpose of the plugin is well mentioned in the same page that is referred here in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're after the 'Display' window.

Go to  `Window > Show View > Other... > Display`

You can now invoke methods in the context of the current breakpoint.

Comment: I did exactly what you said. I typed some commands and nothing happens. An example was "println session" and "println params", but I cant execute it. It seems that is just a 'text editor'.

Comment: @TrtTrt did you press `Execute` or `Ctrl + Enter` as it says in the docs?

Comment: You need to highlight the code and press ctrl-shift-D to execute it. I use this feature every day for Java and Grails. There's another stackoverflow question here with some more details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014068/immediate-window

Comment: This is strange. Anyway whatever code I pass in I get this now, (Groovy) An exception occurred durring evaluation...
@rcgeorge23 if you edit your question I can remove the minus 1 and accept it, as it wont let me now